# F# FS0039 namespace is not defined

Tags: asp.net, f#

Here's a pic of the problem in VS2017:

[image: WTF!!]

The compiler throws:

`FS0039 The namespace 'Web' is not defined.`

But it was ok with 'Web' in the line before it!!

Of course, I have referenced System.Web.Mvc.dll.  In fact the open references  (and code) compiles correctly if I put it in a particular file in the same project (in this case Global.asax.fs).

---

**Update:**

TLDR; the problem mysteriously went away...

After multiple recompiles, restarts & reboots the problem still persisted.  Finally, I manually edited the file order in .fsproj (moving myfile.fs after Global.asax.fs) and it compiled!  Then to check, I moved the file order back to the original order...and it still worked !?!

Not sure what to say.  If anyone has the same problem, know that you're not alone.  Fiddle with it, wait and fiddle some more and the problem will go away ... I think...

Comment: I am not sure whether this is related to an issue I reported to the Visual F# team on GitHub. If it's the same issue causing it, then perhaps there is a totally different actual error or warning in your source. Have a look: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3075

Comment: Thanks @bent.  I thought those issues we're unrelated to my problem, but given my "solution" I'm not so sure anymore...

Comment: I posted a link to this question in 3075 referenced above, but it's possible this deserves being filed separately on GitHub. But it wouldn't help much unless there's a repro - a sample project with the problem, or a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I get this error pretty frequently. I have to close VS2017 and reopen it to make it go away. This is more prone to happen when I rename a file/module.